# Translation of "That must have been a year ago"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, subjunctive

> A: Remember when we had dinner together at that restaurant?
>
> B: That must have been a year ago!

To translate:

> A: Erinnerst du dich, als wir zusammen Abendessen in diesem Restaurant hatten?
>
> B: Das muss vor einem Jahr gewesen sein/wären.

I'm wondering in particular what is the correct translation of "must have been" here. Should I use "muss... gewesen sein" or "muss... gewesen wären"?

Comment: Alternative: "Das muss ja schon (über/mindestens) ein Jahr her sein!" or, more generally applicable, "Das ist ja (ewig her/bald nicht mehr wahr!)"

Comment: @raphael addition: those are applicable if the essence of the statement is to stress that it's been long already. However, none of `ja schon (über/mindestens)` is to be found in the OP's example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The construction is *müssen* + infinitive. "*Gewesen sein*" is the past infinitive of "*sein*" (participle "*gewesen*" + infinitive "*sein*").

"*Wären*" is not an infinitive, you can only use "*gewesen wären*" in a context where the verb comes last (subclause) and is conjugated (e.g., "*Wenn sie dort gewesen wären, ...*").

So only "*sein*" is correct.

> Erinnerst du dich noch daran, wie wir abends in diesem Restaurant zusammen gegessen haben

for example is more natural than your literal translation of "*to have dinner*". "*Abendessen*" has the connotations of a (cold) German evening meal (bread, sausage, etc.), while "*dinner*" in a restaurant means a warm meal with several courses.

Answer (score 0):

> Das muss wohl ein Jahr her sein

translated back leads to

> "This may have been a year ago"

..But it catches the meaning of what you try to say.
Although you use "must" you are not really 100% sure, right?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference in meaning between the English and German versions in the OP. Both express the same vague reference to how long ago this was.